# Calculate checksum for Laboratory Information System (LIS) frames

Tags: c#, checksum

I'm developing an instrument driver for a [Laboratory Information System](https://www.limswiki.org/index.php/Laboratory_information_system). I want to know how to calculate the checksum of a frame.

Explanation of the checksum algorithm:

> 1. Expressed by characters [0-9] and [A-F].
> 2. Characters beginning from the character after [STX] and until [ETB] or    [ETX] (including [ETB] or [ETX]) are added in binary.
> 3. The 2-digit numbers, which represent the least significant 8 bits in    hexadecimal code, are converted to ASCII characters [0-9] and
>    [A-F].
> 4. The most significant digit is stored in CHK1 and the least significant    digit in CHK2.

I am not getting the 3rd and 4th points above.

This is a sample frame:

```
<STX>2Q|1|2^1||||20011001153000<CR><ETX><CHK1><CHK2><CR><LF>
```

What is the value of `CHK1` and `CHK2`? How do I implement the given algorithm in C#?

Comment: i m confusion in what is final ans. it is 4 digit or 2 digit.and i am not getting what i will do after sum of all byte.

Comment: this is sample frame : <STX>2Q|1|2^1||||20011001153000<CR><ETX><CHK1><CHK2><CR><LF> and i want to know what is value of chk1 and chk2 and i am new in this so i m totally blank about how to calculate checksum.

Comment: Like we talked about in chat, we need to know what kind of checksum algorithm the instrument is expecting you to use. Is it a CRC, Fletcher, or something else?

Comment: @Collin this things does not disclose in documentation of instrument just given above explanation.

Comment: Note: This question has also been posted on [Software Engineering SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/152302/how-to-calculate-checksum). I have edited this question to include some context.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Finally I got answer, here is the code for calculating checksum:

```
private string CalculateChecksum(string dataToCalculate)
{
    byte[] byteToCalculate = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataToCalculate);
    int checksum = 0;
    foreach (byte chData in byteToCalculate)
    {
        checksum += chData;
    }
    checksum &= 0xff;
    return checksum.ToString("X2");
}
```

Comment: Let's assume that byte[3] = {0,0,0} gets sent instead of your actual buffer. The checksum is 0, and it's valid... you ought to check for that case, among other things. It's a really weak checksum algorithm (no offense).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one line:

```
return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataToCalculate).Aggregate((r, n) => r += n).ToString("X2");
```

Comment: you are missing "checksum &= 0xff"

Comment: No, this is not needed as the type of `r` is `byte`, it can't go over two letters

Answer (score -4):

```
private bool CheckChecksum(string data)
{
   bool isValid =false

   byte[] byteToCalculate = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataToCalculate);
   int checkSum = 0;
   for ( int i=i i<byteToCalculate.Length;i++)
   {
      checkSum += byteToCalculate[i];
   }
   checksum &= 0xff;

  if (checksum == byteToCalculate[ChecksumPlace]
  {
   return true
  }
  else
  {
  return  false
  }
}
```

Comment: Pls, read Que. I want checksum value of given string but your ans. returning the boolean value.