# Calculate checksum for clinical instrument

Tags: c#, checksum

I need to calculate the Checksum for an analytical laboratory instrument. I have this example:
[image: Example]

I am using the method taken from this post:
[Calculate checksum for Laboratory Information System (LIS) frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947717/calculate-checksum-for-laboratory-information-system-lis-frames)

This is the code from the example that calculates the checksum:

```
    private string CalculateChecksum(string dataToCalculate)
    {
        byte[] byteToCalculate = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataToCalculate);
        int checksum = 0;
        foreach (byte chData in byteToCalculate)
        {
            checksum += chData;
        }
        checksum &= 0xff;
        return checksum.ToString("X2");
    }
```

And this is the code I used to do the image test:

```
        string cStringStx = ((char)02).ToString();
        string cStringEtx = ((char)03).ToString();

        string cStx = CalculateChecksum(cStringStx);//Result: 02
        string c1 = CalculateChecksum("1");//Result: 31
        string cT = CalculateChecksum("T");//Result: 54
        string cE = CalculateChecksum("e");//Result: 65
        string cS = CalculateChecksum("s");//Result: 73
        string cT2 = CalculateChecksum("t");//Result: 74
        string cEtx = CalculateChecksum(cStringEtx);//Result: 03

        int nSum = Convert.ToInt16(cStx) +
                  Convert.ToInt16(c1) +
                  Convert.ToInt16(cT) +
                  Convert.ToInt16(cE) +
                  Convert.ToInt16(cS) +
                  Convert.ToInt16(cT2) +
                  Convert.ToInt16(cEtx);//Result: 302

        string cTot = CalculateChecksum(cStx + c1 + cT + cE + cS + cT2 + cEtx);//Result: D2
```

The checksum of the individual strings is correct, but the sum is not. cTot should be D4, instead it is D2. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the table, [STX] is not considered for the checksum. Its value is 0x02, but the sum is 0x00. This would explain why you have a deviation of 2 between the expected and the calculated checksum.

Comment: If I remove STX, from the numeric total I get 300 in nSum and 70 in cTot and it is not the correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems that you want to **skip** the initial `[STX]` character (`\u0002`) while summing all the others. You can do it with a help of *Linq*:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  private static int CheckSum(string value) { 
    return value == null 
      ? 0
      : value.SkipWhile(c => c == 2).Sum(c => c) & 0xFF; 
  }
```

**Demo:**

```
 string test = "\u00021Test\u0003";

 int sum = CheckSum(test);

 Console.Write(sum.ToString("X2"));
```

**Outcome:**

```
 D4
```

Comment: Your CheckSum function gives me a series of syntax errors, are you sure it's spelled correctly? I entered the reference to Linq.

Comment: @Frank: you, probably, use an old version of C#. I've rewritten it into old style syntax

Comment: I am using visual studio 2010, now i try with visual studio 2019

Comment: Dmitry Bychenko, Your solution works perfectly, thanks. But I don't understand one thing. Before each call to my CalculateChecksum () method returned the correct value, if I use yours it works instead not. For example, if I use int c1 = Leo.CheckSum ("1"), it was correctly 31 before, now it's 49. Can you explain why? Thanks.

Comment: @Frank: please note that `49 == 31h`. I return `int` value which is decimal `49` and you work with *hexadecimal* representation of it : `49.ToString("x2")` which is `"31"`

Comment: Dmitry Bychenko, Ok, Thank you very much!